# Adding an array of properties to an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of `student` objects that has some basic information like Name and Address. I want to be able to add a `tag` property to the object that is based on the user's input

I am acomplishing this with an input like this

```html
<input placeholder="new tag" onInput={(e) => setAddedTag(e.target.value)} /> 
<button type="submit" onClick={() => addTag()}>Add Tag</button>
```

And I am adding the `tag` property to the specific object with this code

```js
const addTag = () => {
  setStudentIndex(students.id - 1)
  students[studentIndex].tag = [AddedTag]
  // needs to add more than 1 
}
```

However this seems to only work with one tag, and if the user adds a second tag it will overwrite the first one. (or it will just crash)
I have tried using the spread operator

```js
students[studentIndex].tag = [...AddedTag]
```

However this instead set the tag to be `['a', 'b', 'c']` when the user had typed in `abc`
How can I accomplish adding an array of string as a prop?

Comment: would combining the previous tags with the newly added tag work for you? `students[studentIndex].tag = [...students[studentIndex].tag, AddedTag]`

Comment: [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried using push()? something like:

students[studentIndex].tag.push(AddedTag);

Comment: I have tried using push before but it is telling me `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Comment: Maybe you could define the structure before using that students arr and then you could acces the array you just defined with push or those spread solutions

Comment: It looks like this was the closest to the solution. The actual issue was I was adding the tag to the objects in the wrong place, so it was adding it to undefined and crashing. Now that I've fixed it, the push method is working.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
const { tag = [] } = students[studentIndex]
students[studentIndex].tag = [...tag, AddedTag]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I got `TypeError: students[studentIndex].tag is not iterable`

Comment: try the edited version

Comment: Now it brings me back to the original problem of it crashing on the second addition

Answer (score 0):

define the tag to be an array within the object. Something like this:

```
const students = [
   {
       name: "xyz",
       address: "abc",
       tag: []
   }
]
```

Then in your code change the following line from:
`students[studentIndex].tag = [AddedTag]`
to `students[studentIndex].tag.push(AddedTag)`

That should do it.

Comment: the data is coming from an api, so I am only able to add the tag after the fact. I'm doing so with a for loop `  for (let i = 0; i < students.length; ++i) {
      const student = students[i];
      student.tag = []
  }`

Comment: So you are doing it before reading from the user input? ?If that;s the case then all you need to do is change the line from `students[studentIndex].tag = [AddedTag]` to `students[studentIndex].tag.push(AddedTag)`

Comment: Yes, I'm adding a tag array to each object so that when the user searches for students.tag it does not crash. I thought a simple .push() would work however it does not

Comment: If you could post your code snippet using push that is getting the error,it will be easier to debug

Comment: `students[studentIndex].tag.push(AddedTag);` Like in the other answer. I think the issue is with adding the `tag` property to the array. So I am going to tinker with that a bit